# How to fix TypeNull error on document object in event method jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events

I have a block of code that I want to place in event handler but I'm getting the error "TypeError: cannot read property 'dispatchEvent' of null". I know the dispatchEvent is called on null object reference which I guessed it is the DOM object.

This is the code (I just learnt it's an IIFE):

```
(function($,document){
  //...lots of code here(minified)...
})(document)
```

Then in my scroll event:

```
$(document).scroll(function(){
  loadData();
});

function loadData(){
  (function($,document){
    //...lots of code here(minified)...
  })(document)
}
```

How do I pass the document value in the function?

I learnt that I can use **$(this).parent()** in the event method for the first argument(***$***) in the IIFE function, like this;

```
$(document).scroll(function(){
  loadData($(this).parent());
});

function loadData(documentSelector){
  (function($,document){
    //...lots of code here(minified)...
  })(documentSelector)
}
```

but what about the second argument(***document***), how do I pass its value?. Please help, I've been battling with this for a while.

Comment: You pass arguments to an IIFE like to any function: `(function (a, b) {...}(ARG1, ARG2));`. Notice, that in your first example, `$` inside the IIFE refers to `document` (which was passed), and `document` argument is `undefined`, as it is not passed at all.

Comment: Yea, I guess. But the the code runs if no event is attached. It's only when I put it inside event handler that I got dispatchEvent on null object error

Comment: Or what's the right way to pass the document object in event handler? For the first argument please

Comment: You can't pass any custom arguments to the actual event handler function, as the handler is called from the event queue, and the event object is passed only. You've to create a wrapper function to pass your own arguments: `element.addEventListener('click', function (e) {handler(e, arg1, arg2);});`. The wrapper can of course be an existing function too, either a declared or stored in a variable or even in an object property.

Comment: If I need to use document object in the wrapper, how will I pass it as argument when calling it in event handler?

Comment: There it is shown in my previous comment, just replace `arg1` with `document`. It's not clear, why you need to pass `document` specifically, as it is available as a global object everywhere in the code.